# hidden Ajax ModalPopupExtender when click outside panal

Tags: asp.net, ajax, facebook

**In ASP.NET , how hidden Ajax ModalPopupExtender when click outside panal (ModalPopupExtender) not when click on button inside panal (such as Facebook photos show)?
thanks**